# reload wisper listeners automatically at every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wisper

I have wisper listeners in the app/listeners directory.

I also have the /config/initializers/wisper.rb

```
module Wisper
  def self.setup
    configure do |config|
      config.broadcaster(:default, Broadcasters::LoggerBroadcaster.new(Rails.logger, Broadcasters::SendBroadcaster.new))
    end
  end
end

Wisper.setup

Wisper.subscribe(ProjectListener.new)
Wisper.subscribe(FeedListener.new)
```

Can I somehow force Rails to reload the Listeners at every request?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try wrapping the subscribes in a `to_prepare` block, something like:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Wisper.clear if Rails.env.development?
  Wisper.subscribe(ProjectListener.new)
  Wisper.subscribe(FeedListener.new)
end
```

`to_prepare` is called once in production and before every request in development environment.

If you subscribe in more than one initializer you could put the `Wisper.clear` in an initializer named '01_clear_subscribers` to ensure the subscribers are only cleared once.

Incidentally you don't need to override `setup` to configure the broadcaster, just do `Wisper.configure do |config|`.

Comment: This works in TDD/BDD mode too:

Wisper.clear unless Rails.env.production?

Comment: It's worth noting that this fixed the problem I had where changes to any of my Rails code resulted in the "A copy of X has been removed from the module tree but is still active!" error. Hopefully, this comment will mean that people will find this solution quicker than I did!

Comment: I ran into this issue in my Rails project and I decided to use `before_initialize` instead of `to_prepare` so that I ensure that the clear runs only once during the initialization process for all environments.