# Downloading and attaching an image given an URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, attachment, rails-activestorage

**Status**

I have to download an image from a 3rd-party URL and attach the downloaded file (a picture in my case) as an attachment to a local object. Thus I created a `PictureLoader` class and written a class method in this class.

**I am doing the following:**

1. `picture = URI.open(image_url)`
2. `object.the_downloaded_picture.attach(io: picture, filename: object.id.to_s+"_picture.jpg", content_type: 'image/jpeg')`

The local server console (=> `rails s`) fails with

`ArgumentError (A copy of PictureLoader has been removed from the module tree but is still active!)`

**GOAL:** I am simply trying to download an image an attach it but I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: How do you call this method? How do you define this `PictureLoader`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A copy of xxx has been removed from the module tree but is still active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636334/a-copy-of-xxx-has-been-removed-from-the-module-tree-but-is-still-active)

Comment: @mechniov


RE "How do you call this method?"
what method?

RE "How do you define this PictureLoader?"
a simple class:
require 'httparty'
require 'open-uri'

class PictureLoader

I will look at your posted answer now!

Answer (score 0):

I deactivated caching in the local dev config + used the "down" gem to download the image. Works perfect!